# Importing/Exporting JointJS Graphs with devs.Model Elements

Tags: javascript, json, jointjs

So I am trying to implement an "Import Graph" feature to my JointJS app. All of the elements I am working with inherit from devs.Model such that,

```
var myCustomShape = new joint.shapes.devs.Model();
```

These shapes include custom attributes on top of devs.Model that include sub-objects and function attributes.

Importing my graph with JSON.parse results in Error:

```
joint.js:13580 Uncaught Error: dia.ElementView: markup required
    at child.renderMarkup (joint.js:13580)
    at child.render (joint.js:13616)
    at child.protoProps.render (joint.js:9692)
    at child.renderView (joint.js:17645)
    at child.resetViews (joint.js:17691)
    at triggerEvents (backbone.js:370)
    at triggerApi (backbone.js:356)
    at eventsApi (backbone.js:155)
    at child.Events.trigger (backbone.js:346)
    at triggerEvents (backbone.js:371)
```

I read on the JointJS docs:

> Keep in mind the general limitations of the JSON format. Some commonly used >native JavaScript data types (including Function, Date, and undefined) are >not supported. The variables that have values of these types will not be >persisted. Among other things, this means that if persistence is important in >your application, you should choose to define custom element/link subtypes >instead of embedding custom functions into default joint.dia.Element and >joint.dia.Link types.
>
> Additionally, if you want to make use of the JSON objects and directly store >them into MongoDB, you should remember its additional restriction on object >keys starting with the . (dot) or $ (dollar sign) symbols. Those are reserved >for internal use of the MongoDB system. This is significant in the context of >JointJS because it precludes the use of CSS-style selectors in the attrs >arrays of your Elements and Links. Therefore, if persistence is important to >you and you want to save data directly to MongoDB, you should always define >custom subelement selectors in the markup of your custom elements instead of >relying on CSS-style selectors.

I am wondering if there are any known work arounds here that I can use to save my graph along with all of my custom elements.  Please be gentle, this is my first javascript app, first time working with JSON and first time working with JointJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answered my own question.
If you inherit from a shape without extending it, there is no need for any markup in your declaration of your new shape. Here is the old way of declaring a shape that I was using:

```
OLD CODE DON'T USE THIS

var myCustomShape = new joint.shapes.devs.Model({
    position: { x:50, y:50 },
    size: { width: 75, height: 75 },
    inPorts: ['Input'],
    outPorts: ['Output'],
    attrs: {
        '.label': {
             text: 'Source',
             fill: 'black'
         },
         rect: {
             fill: 'springgreen'
         }
    },
    type: 'custom.myCustomShape'
});
```

So I switched over to extending the devs.Model shape and then make a new of my type like so:

```
NEW WORKING CODE :)

joint.shapes.custom.myCustomShape = joint.shapes.devs.Model.extend({
            markup: '<g class="rotatable"><g class="scalable"><rect class="body"/></g><image/><text class="label"/><g class="inPorts"/><g class="outPorts"/></g>',
            defaults: joint.util.deepSupplement({
                type: 'custom.myCustomShape',
                size: { width: 75, height: 75 },
                rect: {
                    stroke: '#d1d1d1',
                    fill: 'white'
                },
                circle: {
                    stroke: 'gray'
                },
                '.label': {
                    text: 'Base',
                    'ref-y': -20
                },
                '.inPorts circle': {
                    fill: '#c8c8c8'
                },
                '.outPorts circle': {
                    fill: '#262626'
                },
            }, joint.shapes.devs.Model.prototype.defaults)
        });
```

And is used by:

```
var customShape= new joint.shapes.custom.myCustomShape({
            attrs: {
                '.label': {
                    text: 'My Shape',
                    fill: 'black'
                },
                rect: {
                    fill: 'springgreen'
                }
            },
            position: { x: 50, y: 50 },
            size: { width: 75, height: 75 }
        });
graph.addCell(customShape);
```

When exporting and importing graphs with shapes declared like this, everything works properly.